# image bitmap shows only first item in viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-imageview, aquery

I have ViewPager which in I adding some views programmatically.

Each page has imageview and textviews.

All textviews setted fine but image display only one, I mean there is only one image only in first item of viewPager, the rest doesn't show images

```
private void setValues(){
        final LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        int size = MyApplication.getInstance().getEntityList().size();
        AQuery aq = new AQuery(mActivity);
        for (int i=0;i<size;i++){

            Entity entity  = MyApplication.getInstance().getEntityList().get(i);
            View v = li.inflate (R.layout.product_main, null);
            final ImageView img = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.immage);


            aq.id(R.id.image).image(entity.getMobile_pic(), true, true, mActivity.getCurrentDeviceDisplayMatrics().widthPixels, 0, new BitmapAjaxCallback(){

                @Override
                public void callback(String url, ImageView iv, Bitmap loadedImage, AjaxStatus status){
                    iv.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(loadedImage, 0, loadedImage.getHeight()/2, loadedImage.getWidth(), loadedImage.getHeight()/2));
                }

            });


            ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(entity.getTitle());
            ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.description)).setText(entity.getDescription());

            pagerAdapter.addView(v);
            pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

What is wrong here and why other images don't show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this

`aq = new Aquery(img)` not pass activity.

That's it.